# sas- list concatenation- exception in the last item

Tags: list, sas

I want to create a list to run a proc sql_ union table, to know how many clients id I have.
I wrote the following code to create the list, but I need that for the last table doesn't write "union all"

```
proc sql;
select 
cat(cats('select cid from labo2.', memname),' union all ')
into :listado
separated by ' '
from dictionary.columns 
where libname='LABO2' and name= 'cid' and memname like 'A_%';
quit;
```

How can I do this and in the last line not include "union all"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `separated by` to do this.  Any string may be placed in this, not just a single character.  This works similarly to CATX.

```
proc sql;
  select cats('select cid from labo2.', memname)
   into :listado
   separated by ' union all '
   from dictionary.columns 
   where libname='LABO2' and name= 'cid' and memname like 'A_%';
quit;
```